# Installing TP-Link TL-WDN4800 Adapter with Ath9k

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, kernel

I just bought a wireless adapter and am still trying to install its drivers onto Ubuntu. I have looked up ath9k and seen that it is compatible with kernal module ath9k. I'm new to ubuntu and most of the code is still over my head, and most of the guides that I have read involve connecting to the router which I am unable to do. I am need of figuring out how to install ath9k without any network connection. Appreciate any and all help.

```
    lspci -nn | grep 0208
    01:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Netwrok Adapter [168c:0030] (rev 01)
    uname -r
    3.11.0-15-generic
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of the device from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280 and also: uname -r  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since lspci sees your card the following should work.

1) Get the Atheros module

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-atheros
```

2) modprobe ath9k

```
sudo modprobe -r ath9k
sudo modprobe ath9k
```

Check your Network manager and it should be working.