# Network connection problem with TP-Link TL-WDN4800 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu, pci

I have recently bought TP-Link TL-WDN4800 network card.

But I am suffering low signal strength and also disconnection problem.

> lspci -nn | grep 0280

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros  AR93xx wireless Network Adapter [168c:0030] (rev 01)
```

> uname -r

```
4.4.0-53-generic
```

According to [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/446942), I have to install firmware-atheros package. But, there is no package with this name.

I didn't try my network card with windows. Anyway, what should I do to use TL-WDN4800 without disconnection and low signal strength problems.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Any chance you found a solution to this? I'm running into the same issue now on Ubuntu 21.04.